# JavaScriptのコーディング規約はどの採用が主流ですか？

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptのコーディング規約はどの採用が主流ですか？

・JavaScript style guide（MDN）
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/JavaScript_style_guide
・Google JavaScript Style Guide
http://cou929.nu/data/google_javascript_style_guide/
・Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide
http://mitsuruog.github.io/javascript-style-guide/

nodeとjqueryは下記ですかね？
・Node.js Style Guide
http://popkirby.github.io/contents/nodeguide/style.html
・JavaScript Style Guide（jQuery）
https://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/

またtabか４スペかインデントはどちらが主流ですか？

Comment: 「一番人気のある○○は？」系統の質問は明確な答えがないので恐らく閉じられる質問の対象になってしまうと思うのですが、それは置いときましてタブの置換に関してはSublime Textには対象フォルダの一括変換があるようなので、それで変換するのが良いと思います。

Comment: 「インデントはどちらが良いか」に関する部分を削りました。その上で「主流」の規約があるかに関しては、ある程度客観的に回答が可能だと思いますので、再オープンに投票いたします。

Comment: javascript の場合 4 spaces より 2 spaces をよく見る気がします（し上のスタイルガイド3つでもそうなってます）

Comment: 2 spacesが主流なのですね、ただ見にくくないでしょうか？
メリットは4回押さなくて済むことでしょうか

Answer (score 6, accepted):

例えば Python には [PEP8](https://pep8-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/)、Go言語には[Effective Go、gofmt](http://golang.jp/effective_go#formatting)が、言語の開発者に強く推奨されるコーディング規約として存在します。
しかし、JavaScript にはこれら程に参照され受け入れられている文章・規約がありません。
よって、主流と言えるコーディング規約はありません。

インデントに関してもコーディング規約の一部ですから事情は同じです。

Comment: MDN、4スぺが主流というわけでもないのですね

Comment: こちらで聞く質問ではないようなので他の所にします。